# TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.24.0.1:41096

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, tls1.2

I create network files automatically through node.js.

I am building a test network with 1 orderer, 1 org and 1 peer, 1 cli and 1 ca for test.

When I create the channel using createChannel.sh based on the hyperledger fabric 2.2.1, I get some TLS-related errors inside my order container:

```
TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like
a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.26.0.1:48124
```

I don't understand if the problem is in the yaml files or in another file.
Every help is welcome.

Here is my files:

createChannel.sh

```
# # imports  
. envVar.sh
. utils.sh

CHANNEL_NAME="$1"
DELAY="$2"
MAX_RETRY="$3"
VERBOSE="$4"
: ${CHANNEL_NAME:="canal"}
: ${DELAY:="3"}
: ${MAX_RETRY:="5"}
: ${VERBOSE:="false"}


createChannel() {
    setGlobals 1
    # Poll in case the raft leader is not set yet
    local rc=1
    local COUNTER=1
    while [ $rc -ne 0 -a $COUNTER -lt $MAX_RETRY ] ; do
        sleep $DELAY
        set -x
        ../bin/peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.tx --outputBlock $BLOCKFILE --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA >&log.txt
        res=$?
        { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
        let rc=$res
        COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
    done
    cat log.txt
    verifyResult $res "Channel creation failed"
}


FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/rede


infoln "Creating channel ${CHANNEL_NAME}"
createChannel
successln "Channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' created"
```

crypto-config.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
 
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org2: See "Org1" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: org1
    Domain: org1.com
    Template:
      Count: 1
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    SANS:
        - "localhost"
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

configtx.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
    - &org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org1MSP.admin', 'org1MSP.peer', 'org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org1MSP.admin', 'org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org1MSP.peer')"

        # leave this flag set to true.
        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V2_0 capability ensures that orderers and peers behave according
        # to v2.0 channel capabilities. Orderers and peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V2_0 orderer capability ensures that orderers behave according
        # to v2.0 orderer capabilities. Orderers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 orderer capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V2_0 application capability ensures that peers behave according
        # to v2.0 application capabilities. Peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 application capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 application capabilities, ensure that all
        # peers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    canal:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *org1
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

    SampleOrgs:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults

            Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
            - <<: *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *org1
```

base.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'
services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    dns_search: .
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=rede
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      # The following setting skips the gossip handshake since we are
      # are not doing mutual TLS
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/ca.crt
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

networks:
  rede:

services:
  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - rede
  ca_org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=9055
    ports:
      - "9055:9055"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_org1
    networks:
      - rede
  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: couchdb:3.1.1
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=admin
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=adminpw
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - rede
  peer0.org1.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1MSP
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=admin
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=adminpw
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/peers/peer0.org1.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/peers/peer0.org1.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7080:7053
    networks:
      - rede
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/organizations

    depends_on:
      - peer0.org1.com
    networks:
      - rede
```

networkconfig.yaml

```
---
#
# Copyright Fujitsu Australia Software Technology, IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
#
# The network connection profile provides client applications the information about the target
# blockchain network that are necessary for the applications to interact with it. These are all
# knowledge that must be acquired from out-of-band sources. This file provides such a source.
#
name: "rede"

#
# Any properties with an "x-" prefix will be treated as application-specific, exactly like how naming
# in HTTP headers or swagger properties work. The SDK will simply ignore these fields and leave
# them for the applications to process. This is a mechanism for different components of an application
# to exchange information that are not part of the standard schema described below. In particular,
# the "x-type" property with the "hlfv1" value example below is used by Hyperledger Composer to
# determine the type of Fabric networks (v0.6 vs. v1.0) it needs to work with.
#
x-type: "canal"

#
# Describe what the target network is/does.
#
description: "desc rede"

#
# Schema version of the content. Used by the SDK to apply the corresponding parsing rules.
#
version: 1.0.0
client:
  # Which organization does this application instance belong to? The value must be the name of an org
  # defined under "organizations"
  organization: org1

  # Some SDKs support pluggable KV stores, the properties under "credentialStore"
  # are implementation specific
  credentialStore:
    # [Optional]. Specific to FileKeyValueStore.js or similar implementations in other SDKs. Can be others
    # if using an alternative impl. For instance, CouchDBKeyValueStore.js would require an object
    # here for properties like url, db name, etc.
    path: "/tmp/hfc-kvs"

    # [Optional]. Specific to the CryptoSuite implementation. Software-based implementations like
    # CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js in node SDK requires a key store. PKCS#11 based implementations does
    # not.
    cryptoStore:
      # Specific to the underlying KeyValueStore that backs the crypto key store.
      path: "/tmp/hfc-cvs"

    # [Optional]. Specific to Composer environment
    wallet: wallet-name
#
# [Optional]. But most apps would have this section so that channel objects can be constructed
# based on the content below. If an app is creating channels, then it likely will not need this
# section.
#
channels:
  # name of the channel
  canal:
    # Required. list of orderers designated by the application to use for transactions on this
    # channel. This list can be a result of access control ("org1" can only access "ordererA"), or
    # operational decisions to share loads from applications among the orderers.  The values must
    # be "names" of orgs defined under "organizations/peers"
    orderers:
      - orderer.example.com

    # Required. list of peers from participating orgs
    peers:

      peer0.org1.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

    # [Optional]. what chaincodes are expected to exist on this channel? The application can use
    # this information to validate that the target peers are in the expected state by comparing
    # this list with the query results of getInstalledChaincodes() and getInstantiatedChaincodes()
    chaincodes:
      # the format follows the "cannonical name" of chaincodes by fabric code
      - blockflow-app:v0.1
#
# list of participating organizations in this network
#
organizations:


  org1:
    mspid: org1

    peers:
      - peer0.org1.com
    # [Optional]. Certificate Authorities issue certificates for identification purposes in a Fabric based
    # network. Typically certificates provisioning is done in a separate process outside of the
    # runtime network. Fabric-CA is a special certificate authority that provides a REST APIs for
    # dynamic certificate management (enroll, revoke, re-enroll). The following section is only for
    # Fabric-CA servers.
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca-org1

    # [Optional]. If the application is going to make requests that are reserved to organization
    # administrators, including creating/updating channels, installing/instantiating chaincodes, it
    # must have access to the admin identity represented by the private key and signing certificate.
    # Both properties can be the PEM string or local path to the PEM file. Note that this is mainly for
    # convenience in development mode, production systems should not expose sensitive information
    # this way. The SDK should allow applications to set the org admin identity via APIs, and only use
    # this route as an alternative when it exists.
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/users/Admin@org1.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk
    signedCert:
      path: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/users/Admin@org1.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.com-cert.pem

#
# List of orderers to send transaction and channel create/update requests to. For the time
# being only one orderer is needed. If more than one is defined, which one get used by the
# SDK is implementation specific. Consult each SDK's documentation for its handling of orderers.
#
orderers:
  orderer.example.com:
    url: grpc://localhost:7050

    # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
    # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com
#      sslProvider: openSSL
#      negotiationType: TLS
#      hostnameOverride: orderer.example.com
      # grpc-max-send-message-length: -1
      # grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 360000
      # grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms: 180000
#      grpc.keepalive_without_calls: true
      
peers:
  peer0.org1.com:
    url: grpc://localhost:7082

    grpcOptions:
      grpc.http2.keepalive_time: 15
#      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.com
#      negotiationType: TLS
#      sslProvider: openSSL
#      hostnameOverride: peer1.org1.com

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/peers/peer0.org1.com/tls/server.crt


#
# Fabric-CA is a special kind of Certificate Authority provided by Hyperledger Fabric which allows
# certificate management to be done via REST APIs. Application may choose to use a standard
# Certificate Authority instead of Fabric-CA, in which case this section would not be specified.
#
certificateAuthorities:

  ca-org1:
    url: http://localhost:9054
      # the properties specified under this object are passed to the 'http' client verbatim when
      # making the request to the Fabric-CA server
    httpOptions:
      verify: true
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/ca/ca.org1.com-cert.pem

    # Fabric-CA supports dynamic user enrollment via REST APIs. A "root" user, a.k.a registrar, is
    # needed to enroll and invoke new users.
    registrar: # as an array.
      -  enrollId: admin
         enrollSecret: adminpw
      # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
            ## caName: ca0 no ca name!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be the TLS field is missing in the docker-compose file of the CLI service. Add the following field if you are using CLI for installing and invoking the chaincode.

```
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org.com/peers/peer0.com/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org.com/peers/peer0.com/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org.com/peers/peer0.com/tls/ca.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
../bin/peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.tx --outputBlock $BLOCKFILE --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA >&log.txt
```

Make sure $BLOCKFILE variable is set to
`BLOCKFILE="/channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block`"

And also check you have `./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.tx` channel configuration file, if not you need to generate that using the below command before you create channel. You can read more about configaration transaction generator  [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#configuration-transaction-generator)

```
../bin/configtxgen -profile canal -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```